# DC current source into capacitor - does capacitor voltage rise infinitely?

Tags: power-electronics

I would like to check my understanding.

### **Scenario 1 : Constant Current Source with no parallel resistance**

Consider the following circuit,

[image]

I = C (dv/dt)

Since, I is constant, dv/dt should be a constant slope and capacitor voltage should continue to rise to infinity with this constant slope.

### **Scenario 2 : Constant Current Source with parallel resistance**

[image]

In reality, the current source will have a parallel shunt resistance and as the capacitor voltage rises now due to the 1mA DC current source and through the resistor path, the voltage on the capacitor should not exceed 1.8V due to the voltage drop across the resistor? But won't the ideal current source still be driving 1mA into the capacitor and so the capacitor voltage should still be rising?

Comment: Have you tried analyzing your 2nd circuit with KVL?

Comment: V1 = VR1 + VC1  -> 1.8V = VR1 + VC1, how do I proceed from here?

Comment: Your circuit has two loops, so write an equation for the 2nd loop.

Comment: V1 = VI1 + VC1 -> 1.8V = VI1 + VC1. So VI1 = VR1 when you substitute the two together? I'm not sure where this is going.

Comment: And what equation do you need to add when doing mesh analysis in a circuit with a current source?

Comment: I need to review my mesh circuit analysis. Thank you, I will review that and attempt the KVL again.

Comment: Regarding "In reality, the current source will have a parallel shunt resistance", I am sorry that I will have to destroy your "textbook ideas" but the real current sources are not made this way - by connecting a resistor in parallel to an "ideal" current source; they are made by connecting a resistor in series to an "ideal" voltage source. This here is only a model of the circuit theory. I have no objection to the model but it is good to have an idea of ​​reality because we live there...

Comment: You can get a good idea of ​​how constant current  sources are made in reality by a related [EE question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/479082/61398).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *But won't the ideal current source still be driving 1mA into the
> capacitor and so the capacitor voltage should still be rising?*

Your capacitor will charge to a voltage of 101.8 volts (eventually). This is because that is the voltage scenario that causes all the 1 mA to be taken by the 100 kΩ resistor. In other words, when there is 100 volts across the 100 kΩ resistor, the current into that resistor is 1 mA and the circuit voltages stabilize.

Comment: Why is the resistor taking the full 1mA in the end? It's an ideal current source driving 1mA into a node which has a 100k resistor and a capacitor. Why does the 1mA not keep flowing into the capacitor?

Comment: @AlfroJang80 As the capacitor voltage rises, the voltage across the resistor rises. As the voltage across the resistor rises, more current flows through the resistor. Time passes.... and the charging current into the capacitor is falling and the voltage across the resistor is rising until equilibrium is reached where all the current from the current source is used in sustaining 100 volts across the 100 kohm resistor.

Comment: Ah! So at the start, the capacitor voltage is 0, the current source is pushing 1mA into the capacitor and the resistor has 1.8 (Vdc) - 0V (Vcap) and so pushes 1.8uA into the capacitor. So the capacitor is charging up with a 1.018mA current. The capacitor voltage rises with I = C dv/dt with the current provided by the resistor path linearly decreasing as capacitor voltage rises. After capacitor voltage passes 1.8V, some of the 1mA from the current source goes to the resistor. Capacitor voltage slows down (I is smaller, hence dv/dt smaller).

Comment: ... eventually, the resistor takes the full 1mA and the final capacitor voltage is 1.8 (Vdc) - (-1mA * 100k) = 101.8V. -> steady state.

Comment: @AlfroJang80 if there is 100 volts across the resistor then the lower node of that resistor must be 101.8 volts.

Comment: Yes. This makes perfect sense now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the OP's question (as well as to most of circuit questions) is elementary if well-known elements and basic building blocks can be seen in the circuit diagram. This is the way we act in practice instead blindly analyzing circuits "without seeing the forest behind the trees"...

Following this common sense, here we can see in total three elements - two *voltage sources* in series charging a *capacitor*. The first source (V1) is an ordinary single voltage source producing 1.8 V. The second (I1 + R1) is a *composite voltage source* built, according to the [Norton's idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton%27s_theorem), by connecting a current source to a resistor. It "produces" a voltage drop V = I.R = 100 V across the resistor that is used as an output voltage. The voltages of the two sources have the same polarities (when travelling the loop); so they are summed according to KVL... and the total voltage is Vtot = 100 V + 1.8 V = 101.8 V. The problem of the composite voltage source is its high output resistance that is vital until the capacitor is charging.

At the end of the process (usually above 95% of the total voltage), the capacitor does not play any role and actually there is a voltage source of 101.8 V that is not loaded (open circuit).